# Place an HTML element on a Cesium Entity's position

Tags: javascript, entity, cesiumjs, cartesian, wgs84

I need to define the location of an html element based on the location of a Cesium entity. I've used the mouse position (`Cesium.Cartesian3.clone(movement.endPosition)`), which is in window coordinates, as a test and it works. So I need to get the entity position, transform it to the WGS84 coordinates, transform those to the window coordinates and use them for `element.style.left = window_coord.x` and `element.style.top = window_coord.y`. 

So I get the entity.position and the x, y and z values are right. However when I want to convert them to WGS84 coordinates something goes wrong and I get NaN for lat, lon and height.

These are the variations I've tried, both result in NaN for lat, lon and height:

```
var carto = Cesium.Ellipsoid.WGS84.cartesianToCartographic(entity.position);
or
var carto = Cesium.Cartographic.fromCartesian(entity.position);
or
var ellipsoid = viewer.scene.globe.ellipsoid;
var cartesian = viewer.camera.pickEllipsoid(entity.position, ellipsoid);
var carto = ellipsoid.cartesianToCartographic(cartesian);


var entity_pos = Cesium.SceneTransforms.wgs84ToWindowCoordinates(scene, carto);
element.style.left = entity_pos.x;
element.style.top = entity_pos.y;
```

[image: Console log showing entity.position, carto and entity_pos]

My other idea was manually calculating the WGS84 coordinates but this would be such a dumb workaround. Any ideas on how I could do this without influencing the user experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the entity's position must be done with the `entity.position.getValue(clock.currentTime)` function, because entities can be moving objects with changing positions.

Here's a [demo of an HTML element following an entity position](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/Sandcastle/#c=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).

```
// Create Cesium Viewer
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');

// Create a sample HTML element in the document.
var testElement = document.createElement('div');
testElement.style.position = 'absolute';
testElement.style.border = '2px solid #444';
testElement.style.font = '16px sans-serif';
testElement.innerHTML = 'Testing';
viewer.container.appendChild(testElement);
var isEntityVisible = true;

// Create a sample entity
var entity = viewer.entities.add({
    position : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-75.59777, 40.03883),
    point : {
        pixelSize : 10,
        color : Cesium.Color.YELLOW
    }
});

// Pre-allocate memory once.  Don't re-allocate for each animation frame.
var scratch3dPosition = new Cesium.Cartesian3();
var scratch2dPosition = new Cesium.Cartesian2();

// Every animation frame, update the HTML element position from the entity.
viewer.clock.onTick.addEventListener(function(clock) {
    var position3d;
    var position2d;

    // Not all entities have a position, need to check.
    if (entity.position) {
        position3d = entity.position.getValue(clock.currentTime, scratch3dPosition);
    }

    // Moving entities don't have a position for every possible time, need to check.
    if (position3d) {
        position2d = Cesium.SceneTransforms.wgs84ToWindowCoordinates(
            viewer.scene, position3d, scratch2dPosition);
    }

    // Having a position doesn't guarantee it's on screen, need to check.
    if (position2d) {
        // Set the HTML position to match the entity's position.
        testElement.style.left = position2d.x + 'px';
        testElement.style.top = position2d.y + 'px';

        // Reveal HTML when entity comes on screen
        if (!isEntityVisible) {
            isEntityVisible = true;
            testElement.style.display = 'block';
        }
    } else if (isEntityVisible) {
        // Hide HTML when entity goes off screen or loses its position.
        isEntityVisible = false;
        testElement.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the entity.position.getValue(clock.currentTime), I eventually used var entity_pos = viewer.scene.cartesianToCanvasCoordinates(entity.position.getValue(clock), scratch). Your extra code also thought me a lot!