# Converting latitude/longitude point to x, y points on the screen Cesium

Tags: cesiumjs

I want to be able to check if a given latitude/longitude point is in view in a Cesium globe. Is there a way to convert latitude and longitude to x, y points on the screen, if not then return undefined?

Comment: Improve your question. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: There's an example of converting a Cesium lat/lon position to a screen position in this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57928300/836708