# Cesium Way to position div using lat long

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I have lat long coming from cesium, is there a way use those coordinates to position a div using just HTML CSS JS?

Comment: Try using: `Cesium.SceneTransforms.wgs84ToWindowCoordinates`

Comment: For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57928300/836708